# how to write unit test in jasmine for object.assign

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm not sure how to write unit test in jasmine Js for this javaScript code. Since Im learning the jasmine now. Can anyone help me with this?

```
var gt={
"a1"="abcg",
"a1"="abcf",
"a1"="abce"
"b"="abcd"
}

var eDetails = {
"ab"="xxa"
}

fun(eDetails,dt);

function fun(){
eDetails = Object.assign(eDetails, gt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("should do sth which met my expectation", function() {
    let eDetails = ...;
    let dt = ...;
    let actual = fun(eDetails, dt);
    let expected = ...; //What is your expectation
    expect(actual).toBe(expected );
  });
});
```

Comment: How can write testcase only for the  object.assign

Comment: This is different from your original question. You can do it similiarly by creating an actual and expect, and then expect what is your expectation.